# Matlab: how to solve a binary system of equations?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, equation-solving

I'm trying to solve a system of equation with the following form:

```
a5 + a6 + a7 + f5 + f6 + f7 = 11;
b5 + b6 + b7 + e5 + e6 + e7 = 100;
c5 + c6 + c7 + d5 + d6 + d7 = 100;

a5 + b5 + c5 + d5 + e5 + f5 = 11;
a6 + b6 + c6 + d6 + e6 + f6 = 100;
a7 + b7 + c7 + d7 + e7 + f7 = 100;
```

where all the variables and digits are binaries.

Is there a way to do this in Matlab?

For example, by substituting the binary numbers by there decimal values:

```
a5 + a6 + a7 + f5 + f6 + f7 = 3;
b5 + b6 + b7 + e5 + e6 + e7 = 4;
c5 + c6 + c7 + d5 + d6 + d7 = 4;

a5 + b5 + c5 + d5 + e5 + f5 = 3;
a6 + b6 + c6 + d6 + e6 + f6 = 4;
a7 + b7 + c7 + d7 + e7 + f7 = 4;
```

and tell Matlab somehow that the unknowns should be integers and from the interval [0:1]?

---

Here is the A x = b form:

```
A = [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1;
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0;
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0;
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1];

b = [3 4 4 3 4 4];
```

what would be then the next step?

Comment: You should start by rearranging this into the [standard matrix form for linear simultaneous equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Matrix_equation), *Ax = b* (where the aim is to solve for *x*).  This will at least make it easier to handle, and the notation simpler.

Comment: This looks like a problem for *integer programming with binary variables* which is (if memory serves) NP-complete.  There are 2 approaches in general use: *branch-and-bound* and *enumeration*. Personally, I wouldn't tackle this as a set of simultaneous linear equations as @OliCharlesworth's answer might be read as implying.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I'm not suggesting that one should solve it as a linear Ax + b problem, but that it would certainly be easier to handle the coefficients, etc. if encapsulated in a vector and a matrix.

Comment: okay writing the problem as an Ax = b equation is quite obvious, but how to force Matlab to deliver x with values of either 0 or 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bintprog, if you have the optimization toolbox.

Since there are likely multiple solutions, I'll choose the solution which has the minimum sum.

```
>> A = [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1;
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0;
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0;
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1];

>> b = [3 4 4 3 4 4];

>> bintprog(ones(1,18),[],[],A,b)
Optimization terminated.
ans =
     0
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     1
     0
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer!

It would be great if you tell me also how to get all possible solutions.

Comment: That is a difficult problem in general, one you did not ask for originally. It would involve a branch and bound scheme, where you first ask for all possible solutions such that x(1) == 0, and then where x(1) == 1. Each of those possibilities reduces the problem to one with 17 unknowns. Repeat. Alternatively, what is doable on this problem, you can simply test ALL possible solutions. Since there are only 2^20 = 1048576 of them it won't take too long.

Comment: x = A\b don't deliver solutions in the rang 0 or 1, since this case consist of finding a binary solution.

Comment: I still have a question about your answer:

Comment: You said that your solution which minimize the sum.
How can i change the minimization equation to something like this:
    Minimize sum( (a1-3)^2 + (a2-3)^2 + (a3-3)^2)
for example?

Comment: @user1127977 - It can no longer be solved with bintprog then. If you change the problem, it becomes a different problem (SURPRISE). Use exhaustive enumeration, as I said before, or a branching scheme.

Comment: the problem why i cannot use enumeration here is, that the original equation contains much more unknowns, i just simplified it to explain my problem. So the equations will lead to a number of 300 Millions of possibilities to be checked, which is definitely to much for Matlab (could takes weeks of calculations).
What would be then the alternative?

Comment: Why not tell us EVERYTHING you need up front? Is that really so hard? Are there any other pieces of information you wish to add? Anyway, I already told you the answer. Use a branching scheme. This is simply a recursive solution. Is the first variable 0? If so, then how does that reduce the problem? Repeat. Now, consider if the first variable is a 1. Iterate until done.